Drop_Box_Insert_Error
I have a problem inserting a drop box choice list in a cell using the values of a predefined array. Array name is Local_Cell_ID_List
Here I got the unique values from sheet Arranged
set Arranged=thisworkbook.worksheets("Arranged_Data")
   Dim f, addr$, g&
  With Arranged
   addr = .Name & "!$H$2:" & .[H1].End(xlDown).Address
  End With
  With Synthese_Global
    f = Application.Evaluate("=LET(a," & addr & ",u,UNIQUE(a),HSTACK(u,XMATCH(u,a)))")
    g = UBound(f, 1): .[A2].Resize(g, 2) = f
 End With

so now I want to put the unique values i got now in worksheet Synthese_Global in range A2, i want them to be in choice list in cell B1 for which i tried
redim Local_Cell_ID_List(0 to Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row-1)
Local_Cell_ID_List=application.transpose(range("A2"))

so after that I tried to insert the choice list as:
    With Synthese_Global.Range("B1").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Local_Cell_ID_List"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
  .ErrorMessage = ""
  .ShowInput = True
   .ShowError = True
 End With

but i have the error "Type mismatch" at line
Local_Cell_ID_List =Application.Transpose(Synthese_Global.Range("A2"))


Local_Cell_ID_List is a named range?   Your code works fine for me if I create that name.

Synthese_Global is a worksheet reference?  The error you're getting seems to point to Local_Cell_ID_List not being a valid Name.

Hello Tim Williams, Local_CEll_ID_List is an Array that i got from 'Local_Cell_ID_List = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Arranged.Range("H2"))' and Synthese_Global is from Set 'Synthese_Global = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Synthèse_Globale")'

I realized that i didn't even get the correct values of Local_Cell_ID_List array based on column H (from H2 to last row in same column H) i only got 2 values ("1" and "2" which are the first values => "1" is repeated in first 6 rows and 2 is repeated in second 6 rows) so maybe you could help me with that? I tried With Application.WorksheetFunction
Local_Cell_ID_List = .Transpose(.Sort(.Unique(Arranged.Range("H2")), 1))
End With

Please update your post with the rest of the relevant code

I updated the code

Best approach here, as suggested by @blackcat below, is probably to place the list onto a worksheet and reference it in that location.

This is from Microsoft

xlValidateList: Formula1 is required, Formula2 is ignored. Formula1 must contain either a comma-delimited list of values or a worksheet reference to this list.

According to this a workaround to generate a text string with the calculated values of the actual result, and set the Formula1 parameter to this string.
This is a sample code of it:
Sub validator()
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim a(), str
a = [a22:a24 * B22:B24]   'for simulate a result array

   'Create string of actual values

For i = 1 To UBound(a)
  If Len(str) = 0 Then
    str = a(i, 1)
  Else
    str = str & "," & a(i, 1)
  End If
Next i

ws.Range("A32").Validation.Add xlValidateList, , , str
End Sub


Adapting to actual values:
Let assume that validation list is in column A.
The dropdown required in cell B1.



A




List


Value1


Value2


Value3


Value4


=HLookup(34,G5:L5,1,FALSE)


Value5


Value6


Value7



Adapted code
Sub validator()
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim str As String
   'Create string of actual values

ws.Range("B1").Validation.Delete
ws.Range("B1") = Empty
For i = 2 To ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
  If IsError(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then 'ignore error values in the list. change to: If ws.Cells(i, 1)="N/A" Then
  Else                                    'if it is real string
    If Len(str) = 0 Then
      str = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    Else
      str = str & "," & ws.Cells(i, 1)
    End If
  End If
Next i

ws.Range("B1").Validation.Add xlValidateList, , , str
End Sub

Replace ws.Cells(i, 1) with the desired calculation for the cell.
e.g. call a function process(ws.Cells(i, 1)). Obviously in case of error input the process function must handle the error and the valid data too.
Example:
Function process(b As Variant) As Variant
If IsError(b) Then process = b: Exit Function
process = "My " & b
End Function


...but be aware that str cannot be >255 characters long, or you'll get errors the next time you re-open the workbook.

As @Tim commented if you overstep the 255 character limit a workaround can be to generate the calculated values on an unused part of the sheet, and set the Formula1 parameter to that range of cells.

@Black Cat: I used your code and it's working but i have 2 questions please, I want to exclude the value "N/A" from being added to the choice list and how to use the value chosen, i mean i stored the choice list in cell "B1" so does that mean if I want to use the chosen value i have to use Cells(1,2).value or is there something else i have to add?

Pls. find the adapted code. If you want to get the selected value from the dropdown refer it with ws.Cells(1,2) or  ws.Range("B1") . .Value can be added.

@Black cat: thank you very much, it works perfectly!
